# Unable to login to Bluemix via CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am unable to login to my Bluemix account using CLI.

Here are the steps that I followed:

1. Connected to Bluemix from CLI

   E:\myStuff\Coding\Node.js\CloudantDB-NodeApp>bluemix api https://api.ng.bluemix.net
   Invoke 'cf api https://api.ng.bluemix.net'...

   Setting api endpoint to https://api.ng.bluemix.net...
   OK

   API endpoint:   https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.44.0)
   Not logged in. Use 'bluemix login' to log in.
2. Login to Bluemix

Here is the error that I am getting -

```
E:\myStuff\Coding\Node.js\CloudantDB-NodeApp>bluemix login -u arindam.chattopadhya@wipro.com -o BAS-CES-IBM INTEGRATION -s DEV
Invoke 'cf login -u arindam.chattopadhya@wipro.com -o BAS-CES-IBM INTEGRATION -s DEV'...

API endpoint: https://api.ng.bluemix.net

Password>
Authenticating...
OK

API endpoint:   https://api.ng.bluemix.net (API version: 2.44.0)
User:           arindam.chattopadhya@wipro.com
No org or space targeted, use 'cf target -o ORG -s SPACE'
FAILED
Error finding org BAS-CES-IBM
Organization BAS-CES-IBM not found
```

Comment: Did you try the solution embedded in the error message?  use 'cf target -o ORG -s SPACE'?

Answer (score -1):

The following command works -

```
bluemix login -u arindam.chattopadhya@wipro.com -o 'BAS-CES-IBM INTEGRATION' -s DEV
```